# WebAudio Connecting Stream to Destination Doesn't Work

Tags: audio, webrtc, web-audio-api, mediastream

I get a `MediaStream` containing audio data from `WebRTC`. Let's call this stream `srcStream`.

If I have my HTML

```html
<audio id="audio" controls autoplay></audio>
```

And I run

```js
audioEl = document.querySelector("#audio")
audioEl.srcObject = srcStream
```

I can hear the audio, and I can see the audio element starting to count the number of seconds.

However, I get multiple audio streams, so I would like to do something more general and join all these streams to a single stream.
If I run

```js
audioCtx = new AudioContext()
dst = audioCtx.createMediaStreamDestination()
audioEl.srcObject = dst.stream

src = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(srcStream);
src.connect(dst)
```

The audio shows as playing, but I can't hear any audio played.

**Is there a problem with how I create my destination?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933677&q=webrtc%20silent&can=2) in Chrome.
The solution is to additionally attach the stream to a new audio object, even if it's unused

```js
new Audio().srcObject = srcStream;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check the console for messages about not being able to play due to CORS restrictions.  For WebAudio to be play the audio, you have to have CORS set up correctly on the audio tag source to allow access.

Comment: Thank you. The console has no special message. Furthermore, playing the `srcStream` directly works, it just doesn't work when I construct this destination

Comment: WebAudio is required to produce silent out if you don't have CORS access, even if the audio tag would play out just fine before hooking it up to media stream source node.  It would be really helpful if you provided a snippet with some actual audio that doesn't work with webaudio,